# Show Div When Dates Match Using .Each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of job postings and would like to display a div that say 'New' when the date is equal to today's date.

To create this I have created a javascript code that will execute on a loop for each set of outer div's, but I am having trouble correctly running the .each function.

**Here is the link to a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyccrane/2p9f7/**

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="job-date">07-Feb-13</div>
    <div class="new" style="display:none;">NEW</div>
    <div class="value"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="job-date">12-Feb-13</div>
    <div class="new" style="display:none;">NEW</div>
    <div class="value"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
$( ".outer" ).each(function(i) {
        var jd = $(".job-date").text();
        j = jd.substr(0,2);
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = ( '0' + (today.getDate()) ).slice( -2 )
        $('.value').html(dd + "/" + j);    
        if(dd === j) {
            $('.new').show();
        } else {
            $('.new').show();   
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code appears to do what you want:

```
$(".outer").each(function(i) {
    var jd = $(this).find(".job-date").text();
    var j = jd.substr(0,2);
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = ('0' + (today.getDate())).slice(-2);
    $(this).find('.value').html(dd + "/" + j);    
    if(dd == j) {
        $(this).find('.new').show();
    } else {
        $(this).find('.new').hide();   
    }
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dk4dQ/

Your main problem was that you were missing all of the `$(this).find()` calls. You are iterating through containers. Using `$(this).find()` will get you the controls within those containers. The plain `$()` calls will find all matching elements in the document, which is not what you want.

The `this` in this case refers to the container. Wrapping it in the jQuery function lets us use the jQuery find method to get it's children.

Also, as the others mentioned, you were `show()`ing the div regardless of success or failure, which again is not what you want.

Comment: I had to add 'var' before variable j to get the function to run correctly but it works great. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyCrane ooh, I missed that. Glad I could help. Updated the code for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure what you think the problem is but I could see a couple of issues. Mainly, when you do for example:

```
$('.new').show();
```

you're calling show() on ALL matching elements of class new, not just the one 'under' the outer you're in. Try this:

```
$('.new', this).show();
```

You were setting the new to show whichever way your date comparison went too. I had a stab at updating your fiddle below:

```
$( ".outer" ).each(function(i) {
    var jd = $(".job-date", this).text();
    j = jd.substr(0,2);
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = ( '0' + (today.getDate()) ).slice( -2 )
    $('.value', this).html(dd + "/" + j);    
    if(dd === j) {
        $('.new', this).show();
    } else {
       // $('.new', this).show();   
       // do something different here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Axzr. I was having trouble applying the function to the respective div's within 'outer'.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here. First of all, you're triggering show() regardless of whether the dates match or not:

```
    if(dd === j) {
        $('.new').show();
    } else {
        $('.new').show();   // <-- shouldn't show in this case
    }
```

The second problem is that you're showing everything with the class "new", when you only want to show particular divs. You'll need to give unique IDs to each "new" div, and then fix your code to only show the divs with that particular ID.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a complicated iterator function. All you need is:

```
$(".outer .job-date" ).filter(function() {
   return (Date.parse($(this).text()) / 86400000 | 0) == (new Date() / 86400000 | 0);
}).next().show();
```

- `filter` seems like a better choice for what you're doing than `each`. First we just want the set of elements that have a date equal to today.
- To do that we can take the dates and get rid of the time part. Dates are represented in terms of number of milliseconds since the epoch. By dividing by the number of milliseconds in a day (86400000, or 60*60*24*1000) and then truncating any decimal part (javascript idiom: `|0`) we are comparing the number of full days since the epoch.
- Now with a set of elements containing today's date, `next()` advances every matched element to the next sibling (the hidden div with class `new`), and `show()` shows it.